# Sudden error compiling with webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, pug

I was working on my project without any trouble, until I got this compiling error in every single pug file...

```
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 51793ms
                  Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
          app.bundle.js   953 kB       0  [emitted]  app
    polyfills.bundle.js   206 kB       1  [emitted]  polyfills
       vendor.bundle.js  2.29 MB       2  [emitted]  vendor
      app.bundle.js.map  1.14 MB       0  [emitted]  app
polyfills.bundle.js.map   267 kB       1  [emitted]  polyfills
   vendor.bundle.js.map  2.67 MB       2  [emitted]  vendor
   ../client/index.html  3.05 kB          [emitted]  

ERROR in ./client/app/main/main.pug
Module parse failed: /home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/pug-html-loader/lib/index.js!/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/client/app/main/main.pug Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1573:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:727:47)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:292:15
    at runSyncOrAsync (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:160:12)
    at nextLoader (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:290:3)
    at /home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (/home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at /home/nsanz/Documentos/git/tachology/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:446:3)
 @ ./client/app/main/main.component.js 90:12-33
```

I will be very grateful if someone could help me to solve it, I'm in a rush with this project..

Comment: [Unicode BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in your .pug files? Make sure your editor saves those files as plain TXT without BOM.

Comment: How can I check that? I'm using WebStorm...

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it adding raw-loader to my webpack.make file:

```
loaders: ['raw-loader', 'pug-html']
```

> https://github.com/willyelm/pug-html-loader/issues/25